# Portainer Docker Swarm import secrets to compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, portainer

add Secrets in Portainer swarm and trying to import as variable any one could give example how i can import it to compose

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongodb-sharded:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-sharded
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=mongos
      - MONGODB_CFG_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-cfg-primary
      - MONGODB_CFG_REPLICA_SET_NAME=cfgreplicaset
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=${MONGODB_KEY}
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGODB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker secrets will be mounted as files in the container under `/run/secrets/secret-name` (if no explicit mount point was specified). To use it, the application must be able to read the data from these files. That's not always supported. If anything, only a small part of the available variables can usually specified as file.

The official [Docker mongodb Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) states support only for
`MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE`.

The readme from the bitnami/mongodb-sharded image doesn't provide any info, wether there is support for docker secrets.

The compose file with pre definied secrets for the official image would look something like that:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE: /run/secrets/mongodb-root-username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mongodb-root-password
    secrets:
      - mongodb-root-username
      - mongodb-root-password

  secrets:
    mongodb-root-username:
      external: true
    mongodb-root-password:
      external: true
```

Comment: i just want to make sure im not using the default image from bitname i change the script from fork of bitname and as you explain needs to use The official Docker mongodb Image states support only for ```MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME_FILE and MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE. ```

Answer (score 3):

working with portariner Docker Swarm Secret running mongodb sharded

```yaml
version: '3.7'

secrets:
    mongo-root-password:
      external: true
    mongo-key:
      external: true
  

services:
  mongodb-sharded:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-sharded
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=mongos
      - MONGODB_CFG_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-cfg-primary
      - MONGODB_CFG_REPLICA_SET_NAME=cfgreplicaset
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-sharded-2:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-sharded-2
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=mongos
      - MONGODB_CFG_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-cfg-primary
      - MONGODB_CFG_REPLICA_SET_NAME=cfgreplicaset
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-shard0-primary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-shard0-primary
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=shardsvr
      - MONGODB_MONGOS_HOST=mongodb-sharded
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=shard0
    volumes:
      - 'shard0_data:/bitnami'
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-shard0-secondary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-shard0-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-shard0-secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-shard0-primary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=shardsvr
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=shard0
    volumes:
      - 'shard0_sec_data:/bitnami'
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-shard1-primary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-shard1-primary
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=shardsvr
      - MONGODB_MONGOS_HOST=mongodb-sharded
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=shard1
    volumes:
      - 'shard1_data:/bitnami'
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-shard1-secondary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-shard1-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-shard1-secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-shard1-primary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=shardsvr
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=shard1
    volumes:
      - 'shard1_sec_data:/bitnami'
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-shard2-primary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-shard2-primary
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=shardsvr
      - MONGODB_MONGOS_HOST=mongodb-sharded
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=shard2
    volumes:
      - 'shard2_data:/bitnami'
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-shard2-secondary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-shard2-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-shard2-secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-shard2-primary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=shardsvr
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=shard2
    volumes:
      - 'shard2_sec_data:/bitnami'
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-cfg-primary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-cfg-primary
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=configsvr
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=cfgreplicaset
    volumes:
      - 'cfg_data:/bitnami'
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

  mongodb-cfg-secondary:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb-sharded:4.4
    depends_on:
      - mongodb-cfg-primary
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb-cfg-secondary
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=secondary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_HOST=mongodb-cfg-primary
      - MONGODB_PRIMARY_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-root-password
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/mongo-key
      - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_NAME=cfgreplicaset
      - MONGODB_SHARDING_MODE=configsvr
    volumes:
      - 'cfg_sec_data:/bitnami'
    secrets:
      - mongo-key
      - mongo-root-password

volumes:
  shard0_data:
    driver: local
  shard0_sec_data:
    driver: local
  shard1_data:
    driver: local
  shard1_sec_data:
    driver: local
  shard2_data:
    driver: local
  shard2_sec_data:
    driver: local
  cfg_data:
    driver: local
  cfg_sec_data:
    driver: local
```